# Enviar archivo con fecth al servidor, usando input file

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un `input` `file` en mi `html`:

```
<input type="file" name="name" value="" id="inputFileServer">
```

Este input es para cargar unos archivos excel, donde después de elegir el archivo se presionara un boton, el cual tiene un onclick que lleva a un function en JS

```
function cargar_excel() {

    const data = document.getElementById("inputFileServer").value;

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("ArchivoExcel", data.files[0]);

    fetch("Excel/procesar_excel", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((dataJson) => {
            console.log(dataJson);
        })
}
```

En mi variable data donde tomo el value del input, tengo este resultado:

```
"C:\fakepath\Plantilla.xlsx"
```

una de las preguntas que tengo es:

1- Como tomo el archivo desde la dirección que se está subiendo?

2- Como paso el archivo a mi controller, para comenzar a recorrerlo?

Answer (score 0):

> 1- Como tomo el archivo desde la dirección que se está subiendo?

No tomas la dirección, nadie quiere entregar el nombre de las carpetas cuando sube un archivo, por esa razón el navegador cambia automáticamente el `path` original por la palabra `fakepath`

Lo que se envía es el archivo mismo, no su ruta

> 2- Como paso el archivo a mi controller, para comenzar a recorrerlo

Tu código está bien, salvo un pequeño detalle, tu pones:

```
const data = document.getElementById("inputFileServer").value;
```

Y debería ser:

```
const data = document.getElementById("inputFileServer");
```

Como dato adicional tu pones `data.files[0]` esto es porque en un `input file` puedes subir varios archivo, de esta manera solo subes 1

Ahora como debería verse el controllador

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Cargar(IFormFile ArchivoExcel)
{
   if (ArchivoExcel== null || ArchivoExcel.Length == 0)
   {
        return Json("Error");
   }


   using (var stream = new FileStream("ruta" + ArchivoExcel.FileName, FileMode.Create))
   {
         await ArchivoExcel.CopyToAsync(stream);
   }

   return Json("OK");
}
```